# MergeSort algorithm of 2 predefined sorted arrays. Make 1 sorted array. In C

Tags: c, arrays, mergesort

I have a program in which 2 assorted arrays are filled with bicycles. Now I want to make 1 sorted array out of these 2 preset arrays. I could directly think of the Mergesort method, but I still know how to apply it if you enter something on the terminal itself. However, I do not know how to do it with 2 previously created arrays .. Maybe someone has an idea?

The function should read this:

```
void merge_arrays(Bike* bikes1, int n1, Bike* bikes2, int n2, Bike* bout) { 
//merge funktion
}
```

Bike* bikes1 is the first assorted array of bikes and bikes * bikes2 the second. In Bike * bout the sorted array should be output.

In addition to information:

In bike the following data are stored
Coolness, Wheelsize, Gear, Price.

Sorting is according to the first value, so coolness.

THIS IS MY ACTUAL FUNCTION

```
void merge_arrays(Bike* bikes1, int n1, Bike* bikes2, int n2, Bike* bout) {
    //void merge(int a[], int m, int b[], int n, int sorted[]) {
 int i, j, k;

  j = k = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < n1 + n2;) {
    if (j < n1 && k < n2) {
      if (bikes1 + j < bikes2 + k ) {
        bout [i] = bikes1 [j];
        j++;
      }
      else {
        bout [i] = bikes2 [k];
        k++;
      }
      i++;
    }
    else if (j == n1) {
      for (; i < n1 + n2;) {
        bout [i] = bikes2 [k];
        k++;
        i++;
      }
    }
    else {
      for (; i < n1 + n2;) {
        bout [i] = bikes1 [j];
        j++;
        i++;
      }
    }

  }


}
```

it returns the arrays but not sorted..

Output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeXUJ.png)

Comment: Please post output as text. Only use images when necessary.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a [mcve] in this state we can't reproduce your problem. Please to not use image unless you can't do otherwise, here you can easily copy and paste your output instead of use an image of the output.

Comment: You are comparing pointers to elements of two arrays. Pointers can only be compared if they point to elements in the same array (or to the element that would be just past the end of the array). Also, you should be comparing `Bike`s not `Bike*`s.